# Python 3 on Windows: extend stdin.readline() line buffer size

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, stdin

On Windows, interactive Python `sys.stdin.readline()` truncates Ctrl+V pastes to 512 characters.

How do I extend this limit? I need large pastes for prototyping.

Tried the `fdopen()` trick and it didn't work.

The buffer seems to be 1024 on macOS.

**UPD:** Looks like the buffer size is a [compile-time constant](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/63298930fb531ba2bb4f23bc3b915dbf1e17e9e1/Modules/_io/winconsoleio.c#L30-L31).

In C, it is possible to expand buffer with `setvbuf()`, but this function is not wrapped by Python, which is sad. I guess I'll try to call it in `MSVCRT.DLL` with `ctypes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue41849

- `sys.stdin.readline()` has 512-character buffer, indeed
- `input()` has 16K-character buffer

So currently `input()` can be used as a workaround.

Comment: on mac os, the limit is 1024 with both functions

Answer (score 1):

(On Mac OS)
Adding `import readline` to your python script will extend the limit of `input()`

from https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html

> The readline module defines a number of functions to facilitate completion and reading/writing of history files from the Python interpreter. This module can be used directly, or via the rlcompleter module, which supports completion of Python identifiers at the interactive prompt. Settings made using this module affect the behaviour of both the interpreter’s interactive prompt and the prompts offered by the built-in input() function.

example

```
import readline

data = input()

print(data)
```