# How can I read more than 4096 bytes from stdin, copy-pasted to a terminal on Linux?

Tags: python, stdin, readline

I have this code:

```
import sys

binfile = "data.hex"
print("Paste ascii encoded data.")

line = sys.stdin.readline()
b = bytes.fromhex(line)

with open(binfile, "wb") as fp:
    fp.write(b)
```

Problem is that never more than 4096 bytes are read in the `sys.stdin.readline()` call. How can I make that buffer larger? I tried to supply a larger number to the call, but that had no effect.

**Update** I changed my `stdin` reading code to this:

```
line = ''
while True:
    b = sys.stdin.read(1)
    sys.stdin.flush()
    line += b

    if b == "\n":
        break

print(f"Read {len(line)} bytes")
```

Still run into that limit.

Comment: I have some feeling this is OS-dependent. On which system are you using this?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992674/python-3-on-windows-extend-stdin-readline-line-buffer-size

Comment: @Pac0 Fedora Linux 38

Comment: @Pac0 I try to do that now with `sys,stdiin.read(1)`, but still the limit .... Gues I have to flush it somehow

Comment: You could use a temporary file and read from there ?

Comment: Seems 4096 is also a limit from the terminal, the terminal has already cut it down before executing the command if you ever write the full line / copy paste in some form. How are you calling this from your terminal?

Comment: @Pac0 I am afraid that would be it yes. The problem seems to be coming from my shell not sending more than 4096 bytes to stdin. When I do `cat`, it is limited as well.

Comment: yes exactly same finding on my side, our last comments crossed

Comment: Does the input really need to be bytes, or can you accept a string? Why not just use `input()`?

Comment: In Python on Linux, sys.stdin.readline() is unlimited (i.e. limited only by available memory). Try `f.write('x' * 123456)` to a file named `file.dat`, then run `python -c "import sys; print(len(sys.stdin.readline()))" <file.dat`, it should print 123456. What does it print for you?

Comment: pts, yes `stdin` is unlimited, but the input buffer in the shell isn't.

Comment: Doesn't that suggest that "data processing using copy-and-paste is a poor idea and this entire workflow needs to be re-thought"?

Comment: @BartFriederichs: The truncation to 4096 bytes is caused by none of Python, *cat* or the shell, but by the Linux kernel. See my answer for the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This truncate-long-lines-to-4096-bytes behavior is caused by the terminal (TTY) code in the Linux kernel. (Actually, as part of the truncation, the last byte of the 4096 bytes is also replaced with a newline byte.) By the time the (Python) process reads from the TTY as its stdin, the line has already been truncated. There is no easy fix for your use case, i.e. to prevent truncation when copy-pasting long lines to the terminal window. As a workaround, copy-paste to a file (e.g. `infile.dat`) instead, and then run `python script.py <infile.dat`.

It's easy to reproduce the truncation behavior even without Python, by running `dd bs=65536 of=/dev/null`, copy-pasting a line longer than 4096 bytes, and then pressing Ctrl-<kbd>D</kbd> to indicate EOF. The last line of the output will start with `4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied,`, indicating that only 4096 bytes were read. If you copy-paste multiple long lines, you'll see that each of them will get truncated to 4096 bytes (including the newline byte) separately.

More analysis of this Linux kernel behavior:

- [Linux terminal input: reading user input from terminal truncating lines at 4095 character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015137/linux-terminal-input-reading-user-input-from-terminal-truncating-lines-at-4095/18018473#18018473)
- [Is there any limit on line length when pasting to a terminal in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643777/is-there-any-limit-on-line-length-when-pasting-to-a-terminal-in-linux/643783#643783)
- Both answers above explain how the Linux TTY line editor can be disabled with `stty -icanon`, and this will prevent the truncation. See more details on how to do it in the answers. However, please don't do it in random programs, because it changes other terminal behavior as well (such as detecting Ctrl-<kbd>C</kbd> and disabling input echo), and this will confuse your users.

The byte count limit 4096 is hardcoded to the Linux kernel as [N_TTY_BUF_SIZE](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/841c35169323cd833294798e58b9bf63fa4fa1de/include/linux/tty.h#L249).

The rest of my answer demonstrates how Python and the shell (e.g. Bash) work without truncation, thus they are not causing the issue.

---

This is to demonstrate that Python `sys.stderr.readline()` doesn't truncate, so there is no need to change your Python code.

Python `sys.stdin.readline()` has an unlimited buffer (given that there is enough free memory). I've tried it with Python 2.7, 3.6 and newer Python on Linux.

Here is what I've tried:

- Reading short lines from a pipe immediately (without additional buffering delay in Python):

  ```bash
  $ (echo -n A; sleep .3; echo a; sleep .3; echo B; sleep .3) | python -c "if 1:
    for line in iter(__import__('sys').stdin.readline, ''): print([line])"
  ['Aa\n']
  ['B\n']
  ```

  To try it, run the command without the leading `$`. It works on Linux for me, I think it will work on macOS, Windows and other systems. On Windows, you  may want to drop the `if 1:` and the line breaks.
- Reading short lines as bytes (rather than Unicode characters) from a pipe immediately, in Python 3.x, using `sys.stdin.buffer.readline()`:

  ```bash
  $ (echo -n A; sleep .3; echo a; sleep .3; echo B; sleep .3) | python -c "if 1:
    for line in iter(__import__('sys').stdin.buffer.readline, b''): print([line])"
  [b'Aa\n']
  [b'B\n']
  ```

  To try it, run the command without the leading `$`. It works on Linux for me, I think it will work on macOS, Windows and other systems. On Windows, you  may want to drop the `if 1:` and the line breaks.
- Reading a long (longer than 10 MiB) line immediately, without truncation from a pipe:

  ```bash
  $ python -c "if 1:
        import sys, time; f = sys.stdout
        f.write('A' * 10987654); f.flush(); time.sleep(.3)
        f.write('aaa\n'); f.flush(); time.sleep(.3)
        f.write('B\n'); f.flush(); time.sleep(.3)" |
    python -c "if 1:
        for line in iter(__import__('sys').stdin.readline, ''): print(len(line))"
  10987658
  2
  ```

  To try it, run the command without the leading `$`. It works on Linux for me, I think it will work on macOS, Windows and other systems. On Windows, put the Python code to files `a.py` and `b.py`, and then run `python a.py | python b.py`.

---

In some cases it's useful to pass input as fast as possible (i.e. as soon as the process receives it) to the Python program, i.e. to prevent delay cause by buffering in `sys.stdin`.

Good news: `sys.stdin.readline()` returns the next line as soon as it is available to the process, it doesn't wait for subsequent lines. In a loop, use `for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):`, and don't use `for line in sys.stdin:`, because the latter waits for more input even if a line is available. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28919832/97248 and other answers for details.

`sys.stdin.read(n)` typically has buffering delay: even if the process has already read `n` bytes, `sys.stdin.read(n)` will be waiting for more bytes until its buffer (of typically 8192 bytes) is filled. To avoid this delay in Python 3, use `sys.stdin.buffer.raw.read(n)` instead. This will read at most `n` bytes (*not* Unicode characters), and it returns as soon as at least 1 byte is available. Don't mix it with `sys.stdin.readline()`. In Python 2 and 3, use `os.read(sys.stdin.fileno(), n)` for this. Test the buffering delay using a pipe (e.g. `cat | python ...`), because without a pipe the system may use a terminal (TTY) device, which has line buffering by default, returning data earlier, at the end-of-line.

---

This is to demonstrate that it's not the shell that causes truncation. Here is how:

- On your regular Linux GUI, run any of these commands (without the leading `$`):

  ```
  $ xterm -e dd bs=1 status=progress
  $ konsole -e dd bs=1 status=progress
  $ gnome-terminal -- dd bs=1 status=progress
  ```

  A new, empty terminal window will appear.
- In anther program, copy a line longer than 4096 bytes to the clipboard (alternatively, you may copy a text containing multiple lines, some longer, some shorter).
- Paste it to the new, empty terminal window. If unsure, press Shift-<kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste. If that doesn't work, use Ctrl-Shift-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. If that doesn't work either, use *Edit / Paste* in the menu.
- Wait a second, press *Enter* in the window. *dd* will display something like *... bytes (...) copied, ...*. The byte count will be smaller than expected, indicating line truncation at 4096 bytes.
- You can close the window now. Or just press Ctrl-<kbd>C</kbd> or Ctrl-<kbd>D</kbd> to exit from *dd*, causing the window to close.

This demo has proved that truncation happens even if there is no shell (or Python process).